# Number of 7-digit numbers divisible by its units digit problem

Tags: number-theory

How many seven-digit numbers can be divisible by its unit digit?
For example, 1,000,001, 1,000,002, 1,000,004, 1,000,005, and 1,000,008 are valid.

Comment: What have you tried?  How many seven digit numbers end in $7$?  How many of them are divisible by $7$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $9,000,000$ $7$ digit numbers from $1,000,000$ to $9,000,000$ and for each of the $10$ digits there are $900,000$ number ending with that digit.

None of the numbers ending with $0$ are divisible by $0$.  So those $900,000$ fail.

All the numbers ending with $1,5,$ and $2$ are divisible by $1,5,$ and $2$ so that is $2,700,000$ million that work.

For the other odd digits, $k$ and those digits are relatively prime to $10$ the roughly $\frac 1k$ of them in be divisible by $k$.

So for $3$, $300,000$ will be divisible by $3$.

For $7$,  we expect there to be $\frac {900,000}7= 1,000,007\approx 128571.43$  of them divisible by $7$.  So there will be either $128571$ or $128572$.  The first number $1,000,007$ has has remainder $1$ when divide by $7$ so $1,000,017$ with have remainder $4$ when divided by $7$, and $1,000,027=7*142861$ will be divisible by $7$.  Every seventh number up to $9,999,997$ will be divisible by $7$.  So that is $128572$ more.

For $3$, $100,000$ will be divisible by $9$.

Because $\gcd(10,2)=2$ all then numbers ending with an even number, $k = 2m$ will be even and $\frac 1m$ of them will be divisible by $m$.

So for those ending with $4,6,8$ then $450,000$ ad $300,000$ and $225,000$ will be divisible.

So total is $3*900,000 + 300,000 + 128572 + 100,000 + 450,000 + 300,000 + 225,000 = 4203572$

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are well known divisibility tests for each of the digits 1 through 9 (we obviously don't have to consider divisibility by 0). This should generate 9 different integer programming problems in 7 variables each, many of which I presume are easy to compute by hand, but some of which are probably a pain.

I would go implement a small program to check these 9 rules and then call it a day. If you for some reason don't want to use a computer for this (like if you are tying to make this a challenge problem for others) I would seriously take a good hard look at how difficult this is to finish by hand, particularly if you don't recall all the divisibility rules by heart.

Comment: A quick google search shows that the divisibility by 7 rule is the only one that is remotely close to being a headache, so this could be doable by hand.

Comment: Don't need divisibility test.  If $10$ and $k$ are relatively prime $\frac 1k$ of the numbers will be divisible by $k$.  If an if $\gcd(10,k) \ne 1$ then $\frac {\gcd(10,k)}k$ of the numbers will be divisible by $k$.

Comment: So as there are $900,000$ that end with $k$ there will be $900,000(1 + 1 + \frac 13 + \frac 12 + 1 + \frac 13 + \frac 17 + \frac 18 + \frac 19)$ that are divisible by $k$.

Comment: @fleablood Is this not going to run into a problem with some fringe cases? Might the count not be off by one or two? For instance, the number you just posted is not an integer.

Comment: $7$ is the only fringe case. $900,000= 128571*7  + 3$.  And so as the third $1,000,027$ and the last $9,999,997$ are divisible by seven a "extra" cycle fits in.  So round up by 1.

Comment: I do not know how to do programming, so do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @FamousMichaelWang See fleablood's answer for a non-programming, and quite honestly all around better way of solving the problem.

Comment: @Valborg I already accepted his answer and upvoted it.

Comment: @FamousMichaelWang Then I do not understand your comment. If you do not know a good language to write a program in for this problem, and you already have a non programming answer, what are you looking for in terms of suggestions?